# Can not show bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap modal runs very well when i use that in separate file, but when i include that to my template, it does not work. I don't know why i can not open it , it's just open and immediately disappear. It should appear until i click the button close. Does any one of you have any idea about this problem? Can you help?
This is my modal

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button></center>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Do you want to delete it?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <a href="error_delete.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: These kind of questions are very difficult to answers, because this could be only replicated in your system/application. Identify why it is happening and please come up with the specific problem..

Comment: yep, but i can not know how to fix, just raise the question and hope that somebody can help

Comment: What else you have in this page? The other codes.. So that we can replicate in our system atleast..

Comment: i think i have to find out it by myself, anw thank you for your advise.

Comment: Dnt mind please.. But it is impossible for us to tell what's happening in your code for this behavior without seeing all of it.. Anyways.. Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working modal:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yqcfwWkI1aC3VSS3aNil?p=preview

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button>
```

```
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Do you want to delete it?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <a href="error_delete.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

There are some issues in your HTML.

Comment: Dear everybody, first of all, thank you a lot for helping with your idea, now i fixed my problem, i forgot to add a link to js of the bootstrap modal so the code can not run, after adding the link to js my code run well.
anw, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button></center>
```

please remove "center" from your html.

and you need to close a div at the end.

Answer (score -1):

There could be chance for same template in your application, please search application code with modelID.